# How to arrange my entities so a Shop can have Products from a Supplier?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm creating a Platform where Suppliers have Products that Shops can choose, add to their Shop and start selling.

My situation is as follows:

- A Supplier can have many Products (for example: 'T-shirt', 'Iphone Case') (**Supplier->product: One-To-Many**)
- A Supplier Product can have many SKU (for instance: 'T-shirt Small Black', 'T-Shirt Small White') (**Product->sku: One-To-Many**)
- A Shop should be able to "copy" Products from the Supplier, So would I need a Shop_Product table here? (**Shop->Product: One-To-Many**)

The main problem is that my Shop has SKUs from the Supplier but no Products. If I add a Shop_Products table representing a relationship, then how should I "couple" my Shop_Skus to that table?

### Should I add a Shop_Product table, next to the existing Shop_Sku table?

My current database structure is depicted in the diagram below:

[image]

With a Shop_Product column it would look like this

[image]

But then there is no relationship between the Shop_Product and the Shop_Sku which makes this structure irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your desired schema correctly, then you do have a relation between `shop_skus` and `shop_product`, being `product_id`. If you `JOIN` `shop_skus` and `skus` and then that result with `products`, you should end up with the products that your shop skus refer to. You can then compare these `product_id`'s found to the ones stored in `shop_product` to make relations.

To put in more of a query form:

```
SELECT * FROM shop_skus 
    JOIN skus ON shop_skus.sku_id = skus.id 
    JOIN products ON products.id = skus.product_id
    JOIN shop_product ON shop_product.product_id = products.id;
```

This would allow you to access `shop_skus` information and their corresponding `shop_product` information.

Comment: Can you illustrate a little more clearly please? I'm not sure if I understand. Should I join the Shop_Product and the Skus table? Or which ones do you mean?

Comment: I added a proposed query to the answer. Each row here would contain shop_skus and related shop_product information to that shop_skus

Comment: I'll give it a try. So the propsed model seems fine to you? To have a shop_sku AND a shop_product? Thank you for your time!

Comment: That's not really a question I can answer. If the tables are needed then they are needed. If you find yourself repeating data or having to "hack" data to fit into current tables, then modification or addition of tables is usually a good step to take, but that's really for you to decide.